# Transposing a table in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with only one row of data.

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 30 | 50 |

I need to transpose it for presenting in a table:

| Data Point | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | 30 |
| C | 50 |

I've tried using df.transpose() but I end up with the index value as header for both columns:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | 30 |
| C | 50 |

Should I be trying to add a column or rename the index first? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could call `reset_index()` after transpose and then rename the columns (By setting `df.columns` to `['Data Point', 'Value']` for example). Is that the output you're looking for?

Comment: You're using Pandas, right? Please [edit] and add the tag for it.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: @BasvanderLinden - that's done it perfectly thanks.